# android resource linking failed after add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in manifest

Tags: android, android-studio, android-10.0

I have create excel file in my android project, but in android 10 can not create excel file.. so i have tried add

> android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

in my manifest file but it show error like this

[image: errormanifest]

this is my gradle
[image: mygradle]

anyone can help me? thankyou ..

Comment: Your gradle version may be too old to understand what that XML field means. Whats your gradle version?

Comment: @DanBaruch my gradle version is 4.6

Comment: Android Studio sometimes does a poor job of explaining build errors. You might try doing a command-line build, as those often give better error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app targets Android 10 (API level 29) or lower, you can temporarily opt out of scoped storage in your production app. If you target Android 10, you need to set the value of [**`requestLegacyExternalStorage`**](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-in-production-app) to true in your app's manifest file:

Set `compileSdkVersion` & `targetSdkVersion` 30

```
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId ""
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
```